# CSS fixed alignment?

Tags: css

I've got a bit of a problem I can't solve. So basically I've got a fixed feedback button on my screen, looking like this:

```css
.feedback-button-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!-- When Modal opens <body style="padding-right: 17px;">
<body>
  <div class="feedback-button-container">
    <a>
      <button class="feedback-button">Give Feedback</button> 
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've also got a modal. When I open the modal it adds a padding of 17px to the right of `<body>`, this way the scrollbar will hide when the modal is open. The problem is that when I open the modal, because of the increased 17px of padding my feedback button shifts to the right. Is there some easy way to fix this?

EDIT:
I made a mistake in my wording, the 17px of padding aren't supposed to hide the scrollbar, they're supposed to add the space that the scrollbar left when overflow:hidden;

Comment: You question needs more data... but try this   right: calc(15% - 8px);

Comment: @Sfili_81 added more data, if you need some more please ask, and didn't work sadly, still shifted to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the scrollbar from the modal rather than adding a padding to hide it. You can try `overflow:hidden` to do this?

Comment: When I try this everything starts shifting to the right, not only the fixed feedback button

Comment: Did you remove the padding-right: 17px; from the body when you tried it? If you could paste all of the CSS/HTML you have. I'll take a proper look.